# What's the time complexity of the following database query?

Tags: sql, database, relational-database

Suppose I have the following schema for recording the results of professional tennis matches:

```
DATE, PLAYER_ID, RESULT, SURFACE
```

A simple query like searching for PLAYER_ID would run in O(log(n)) time, using a standard binary search or similar. Assuming a relational database system like PostgreSQL or MySQL and assuming an appropriately indexed table, what would be the time complexity of the following query:

```
Retrieve all players where the result of the last match was a WIN and the last five surfaces have all been 'CLAY'.
```

I wrote the query in English rather than SQL but I hope it's sufficiently clear.

Comment: The time complexity depends on the actual query and how it is optimised. Are you using `ROW_NUMBER` to get the most recent 5 games for each player or a correlated sub query?

Comment: It would be a correlated sub query